# Workfront RESTful API Endpoint & Payload for initiating a Interactive Proof

Tags: adobe, workfront-api

So the Adobe documentation or the lack of it has me perplexed. I am trying to understand the sequence of calls needing to be made to initiate an interactive proof in Workfront. (Use case: Web URLs will be provided as part of an input for Review & Approval of a web Page)

Based on article - https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/workfront/using/adobe-workfront-api/tips-troubleshooting-apis/api-create-proof-options-json.html?lang=en

it appears that i need to first use JWT exchanged OAuth token (This works) to call a createProof action on the DOCU API followed by using a ProofHQ token i am anticipating the above call to return and to be used further with ProofHQ SOAP/REST APIs for updating the proof.

My questions are:

There is no swagger definition and/or the API explorer doesnt make it easy to understand how Workfront expects the /DOCU call to be Posted for a "CreateProof" action, when interactive & otherwise. I understand there are many APIs for managing/setting stage(s), reading/completing stages etc but i am at this point just trying to initiate a proof and set the project owner as the actor for the First stage.

Any pointers or samples would be grately helpful.

PS: On V16.0 of the Workfront REST API.

There is no clear documentation for how to initiate proofs in Workfront nor a Swagger/OpenAPI Spec.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to use the Workfront API to create a proof, you will need to create an api key for a user or users.

Everything is available [Adobe Workfront Objects And Endpoints](https://developer.workfront.com/)

The only thing that it doesn't explain well is the advanced proofing options, so this is what you are going to need.

This is the json key (advancedProofingOptions) so this is what you will need for the payload, just remember that this is a json payload.

```html
advancedProofingOptions = {
    "stageBasedVisibility": 0,
    "hasMessage": true,
    "message": "",
    "isOneApproval": false,
    "subject": "",
    "hasElectronicSignatures": false,
    "hasPublicSharing": true,
    "customfields": [],
    "hasCustomMessage": false,
    "isLoginRequired": false,
    "templates": [],
    "hasSelfClose": false,
    "canDownload": true,
    "hasSubscription": false,
    "stages": [
        {
            "deadlineDate": null,
            "isPrivate": true, //
            "lockOn": 3,
            "isMandatory": true,
            "parentPosition": null,
            "activateOnDecision": null,
            "deadlineTime": null,
            "name": "Stage 1",
            "deadlineCalculateOn": null,
            "deadlineBusinessDays": null,
            "activateOnDate": null,
            "isOneApproval": true,
            "position": 1,
            "activateOn": 1,
            "recipients": [
                {
                    "permissions": {
                        "shareProof": true,
                        "resolveCommentsAndActions": true
                    },
                    "role": 3, // This is the users role
                    "email": "**USERS_EMAIL_ADDRESS_IN_WORKFRONT**",
                    "isPrimaryDecisionMaker": false,
                    "recipient_id": "",
                    "notifications": 9, // This is the users notification type
                    "name": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "position": 2,
            "deadlineCalculateOn": null,
            "isPrivate": false,
            "deadlineTime": null,
            "isMandatory": true,
            "activateOnDecision": 1,
            "activateOnDate": null,
            "activateOn": 8,
            "recipients": [
                {
                    "permissions": {
                        "shareProof": true,
                        "resolveCommentsAndActions": true
                    },
                    "role": 5, // This is the users role
                    "email": "**USERS_EMAIL_ADDRESS_IN_WORKFRONT**",
                    "isPrimaryDecisionMaker": false,
                    "recipient_id": "",
                    "notifications": 5, // This is the users notification type
                    "name": ""
                }
            ],
            "lockOn": 3,
            "deadlineDate": null,
            "name": "Stage 2",
            "isOneApproval": true,
            "deadlineBusinessDays": null,
            "parentPosition": 1
        }
    ],
    "isAutomatedWorkflow": true,
    "parentFileToken": null
}
```

Heres the integer values associated.

```html
Roles:
READ_ONLY                                     = 1
REVIEWER                                      = 3
APPROVER                                      = 4
REVIEWER_AND_APPROVER                         = 5
AUTHOR                                        = 6
MODERATOR                                     = 7

Notifications:
ALL                                           = 1
REPLIES_TO_COMMENTS                           = 2
DAILY_SUMMARY                                 = 3
HOURLY_SUMMARY                                = 4
DECISIONS                                     = 5
FINAL_DECISION                                = 6
DISABLED                                      = 9

Proof Lock Types:
MANUAL                                        = 1
NEXTSTAGE                                     = 2
DECISIONS                                     = 3
NEVER                                         = 4

Activation Type:
CREATION                                      = 1
DEADLINE_PASSES                               = 2
DATE_TIME                                     = 3
ALL_DECISIONS_APPROVED_OR_CHANGES_ON_PARENT   = 4
ALL_DECISIONS_APPROVED_ON_PARENT              = 5
ALL_DECISIONS_ON_PARENT_STAGE                 = 6
MANUALLY                                      = 7
```

If you need anymore help let me know.